# Delay between each API request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use a API to get price data. I need to send 100 requests, I need to have a delay between every request. Too not get a 429 Error. How can I achieve this in a practical way. I'm using NodeJS.

```
/* Get Sparkline data from CoinGecko*/
function getSparklineData (marketDataUSD) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        //Get sparkline for every id in marketDataUSD
        marketDataUSD.forEach((coin) => {
            // Get API market data from CoinGecko
            let reqSparklineDataUSD  =  unirest("GET", "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/"+coin.id+"/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=24hours");

            //Wait for response from CoinGecko
            reqSparklineDataUSD.end((resSparklineDataUSD) => {
                //Checking for request errors
                if (!resSparklineDataUSD.error) {
                    console.log(coin.id)
                    // console.log(resSparklineDataUSD.body.prices)
                    resolve(resSparklineDataUSD.body)
                } else {
                    console.log("Something went wrong:\n"+ resSparklineDataUSD.error)
                    reject()
                }
            });
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: your code will attempt to resolve the promise more than once (since the call to resolve is in forEach) - your first task would be to "promisify" the `unirest` call, and then you can add a delay

Comment: something like https://jsfiddle.net/u317dn2y/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said how you want to store the results, but here's one approach that will work on any vaguely-up-to-date version of Node.js that stores them in an array.

First, let's do a function returning a promise that does the request for a single coin. Apparently the `unirest` function's return value **is** a promise, so:

```
async function getCoinGecko(coinId) {
    const reqSparklineDataUSD = await unirest("GET", "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/"+coinId+"/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=24hours");
    return resSparklineDataUSD.body;
}
```

And let's give ourselves a promise-based `setTimeout`:

```
// A promise-enabled delay function
function delay(ms, value) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, value));
}
```

Now we can use an `async` function that returns a promise of an array of results (for instance):

```
async function getSparklineData(marketDataUSD) {
    const results = [];
    let first = true;
    for (const {id} of marketDataUSD) {
        if (first) {
            // Don't delay on the first loop
            first = false;
        } else {
            // Delay on the second loop onward
            await delay(lengthOfDelayInMS);
        }
        // Get this result
        results.push(await getCoinGecko(id));
    }
    return results;
}
```

Or here's a version of that last function that returns a promise of a `Map` of coin ID => data:

```
// An async function returns a promise and can use `await` to wait for promises
async function getSparklineData(marketDataUSD) {
    const results = nw Map();
    let first = true;
    for (const {id} of marketDataUSD) {
        if (first) {
            // Don't delay on the first loop
            first = false;
        } else {
            // Delay on the second loop onward
            await delay(lengthOfDelayInMS);
        }
        // Get this result
        results.set(id, await getCoinGecko(id));
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Note that the whole `new Promise` is unnecessary because `unirest` already returns a promise. Also instead of the DIY delay function you can use `const delay = require('util').promisify(setTimeout)`.

Comment: @CherryDT - It does? *sigh* Thanks. :-) Silly of me to assume it didn't from how the OP's code used it.

Comment: Yeah you didn't have to know, but this way the answer is improved anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

`unirest` request objects are promises, so you should use that instead of creating promises with `new Promise`. And then use `await` to sequence the requests:

```
function async getSparklineData (marketDataUSD) {
    let results = [];
    for (let coin of marketDataUSD) {
        let reqSparklineDataUSD = await unirest.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/"+coin.id+"/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=24hours");
        console.log(coin.id):
        results.push(resSparklineDataUSD.body);
    }
    return results;
}
```

The caller could catch any errors:

```
getSparklineData(marketDataUSD)
    .then(results => process(results))
    .catch(err => console.log("an error occurred", err));
```